# Dreamweawer8

Tags: dreamweaver

У меня что-то левое творится с 8м дримвивером: при открытии файлов в кодировке ANSI он удаляет все русские символы. Ничего в настройках не менял - раньше все было нормально.
Никто не знает почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше с этим вопросом обратитеcь на [БитКод](http://user.hashcode.ru/)! Если никто не поможет то попробуйте так: откройте блокнотом файл, скопируйте весь текст, откройте  Dreamweawer и вставте туда если так сработает то поменяйте в настройках кодировку открытия файлов а иначе поменяйте стандартную кодировку в настройках!

Comment: а где в дримвивере поменять стандартную кодировку?
*скорей всего в ней все дело